# CSS wrapper div height: 100% not covering full page height

Tags: jquery, html, css

When there is not enough content in the div id="content" the red wrapper fills 100%, but when the content gets longer, the red wrapper does not fill 100% screen height and the content div overflows.

The code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JAbuq

Here is the image to demonstrate, re-size the browser to a smaller height. I need this for a mobile browser display.

[image: Small browser.]

Comment: The content *is* 100% of the window height. When you scroll, you're scrolling past 100% of the window's height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `min-height: 100%` instead of `height: 100%` to allow the wrapper to grow beyond the browser viewport height:

```
#content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: none;
  overflow: visible;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/niCfJ/

Answer (score 0):

This is because your content-wrapper is 100% of the size of the WINDOW, not the content. When the content is larger than the window, it bleeds beyond the wrapper.

Changing height to min-height in `#content-wrapper` will solve this issue:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mazBd/

Answer (score 0):

the white container goes out because of padding and margin. The body has some initial margin. I've changed it, give a look here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eiocy/